# Play on Linux is broken for Ubuntu 12.10 (64bit)

Tags: playonlinux

I have read a few threads about how to get Play on Linux to run. But the only solution seems to be to reinstall to 32-bit.

Do anyone here know about if there are a workaround without having to reinstall to a 32-bit version?

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Package "ia32-libs" enables greater 32bit (x86) apps compatibility with Ubuntu LTS 14.4 including Wine.

I solved a significant part of my compatibility problems with Wine after installing it, however I would like a better confirmation from you guys! Roland, I believe this action solves most of your problems!

See how on this text:

"
Ubuntu 64-bit users:

If you use the 64-bit version of Ubuntu (12.04, 11.10 etc), then even after doing all this, “Foxit” still won’t work. That’s simply because, Foxit only has a 32-bit version and for an any application that’s created to run under 32-bit processor instructions should undergo few changes in order to support the 64-bit instructions.

But you can install a special software library that “fakes” (emulates) a 32-bit processor using your actual 64-bit CPU and the program should run without issues. In Ubuntu (plus, GNU/Linux in general), we need a library called “ia32-libs” for that.

It could be because this library has a shi* load of dependencies  (needs a lot of individual packages, about 70-80MB to download), Ubuntu does not come with it pre-installed.

So, for all ya 64-bit users, after following all the above steps, there’s this one last step that you gotta do before you can enjoy our naughty little “Foxit”, and that is installing this software library. For that, open your Terminal window and enter the below command.

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

That’s it, now it should work. A big thanks goes to “robert” (in the comment section), couldn’t have done it without you mate!, thank you  .

But as this needs a lot of libraries (somewhat an “unnecessary burden”, if you won’t really be running 32-bit apps in 64-bit Ubuntu that is), unless you really can’t live without “Foxit”, I humbly suggest that you try something else, “qpdfview” for instance?. *

Oy Gyan!, BTW, why did the default Foxit “.deb” installation fail?

I honestly don’t know. But then again, that “.deb” file was last released more than two years ago!, so perhaps it’s some sort of an incompatibility issue.

Anyhow, if you’ve been having troubles properly installing or running Foxit PDF reader in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot or 12.04 Precise Pangolin then that’s one way to fix it (hopefully  ). Enjoy!.
"

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and paste this code. this will sort out your problem.

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add - sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_natty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It says it dependant on wine, wine-stable or wine-unstable.